# $G$-equivariant Map between cosets implies they are conjugate?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have a group  $G$, and subgroups $H$ and $K$ and a $G$-equivariant map between $G/H$ and $G/K$, then I believe that I can show that $H$ and $K$ are conjugates, i.e. $H = gKg^{-1}$ for some $g \in G$, but can it also be shown that for another $g$ that $H$ is actually a subgroup of $gKg^{-1}$?  If so, what direction should I take to show that I can construct this subgroup?

Comment: You won’t be able to show that $H$ and $K$ are conjugate unless the map is a bijection.

Comment: @Kade In general it can be proven that the assertion $\mathrm{Hom}_{\operatorname{\mathit{G}-\mathbf{Ens}}}\left(\left(G/K\right)_{\mathrm{s}}, \left(G/H\right)_\mathrm{s}\right) \neq \varnothing$ is equivalent to the claim that there exists $s \in G$ such that $sKs^{-1} \subseteq H$, where the subscript index $\mathrm{s}$ refers to quotients by the *left* congruences modulo the respective subgroups (one must not forget that there also exist *right* congruences modulo subgroups, and it should be made explicit whether one is referring to the left or right lateral).